# Descargar archivo csv directamente en navegador web

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Tengo una aplicación web aspx con código C# detrás. Lo que intento hacer que cuando el usuario manualmente cliquee en el botón Descargar, independiente al navegador, el archivo pueda descargarse inmediatamente en el repertorio de descarga.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: que es el "repertorio de descarga" ? porque la descarga debe depender del navegador ?

Comment: hola, lo que pasa que si usas Chrome o FireFox cuando uno descara un archivo se manda a la carpeta de descargas. A eso me referia con dependiendo del navegador pero que se descargue a la carpeta de descarga del computador

Comment: off topic esta es la pregunta 1.000 1K mil Saludos

Comment: @Aarancibia si lo que quieres es que el servidor elija en qué carpeta del cliente se debe guardar el archivo, me temo que es **imposible** por seguridad de los usuarios. Imagina una aplicación que detecte que el cliente utiliza sistema operativo Windows y le permita crear, sobreescribir o eliminar(!) archivos de la carpeta `C:\Windows` sin consultar al cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descargar el archivo podrias usar algo como ser

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

Response.WriteFile("ruta archivo");

Response.End();
```

Imagine el csv esta en un archivo por eso el uso del `Response.WriteFile()` pero sino tambien puedes usar el `Response.BinaryWrite()`

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Pero el "Ruta de archivo" cual seria? como va a saber que se tiene que descargar localmente?

Comment: La ruta es donde generes el csv en el servidor web. No has mencionado como generas el archivo si es que lo grabas fisicamente en una carpeta temporal dentro del servidor web o si lo generas en memoria y lo envias al cliente.

Comment: Gracias, lo probe y me funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

Para descargar un `.csv` también se puede usar un `ContentType="text/plain"`

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType="text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=" + nombreArchivo + ";");
response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("miArchivo.csv"));
response.Flush();    
response.End();
```